# Invalid module names [Odoo 15]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

Im trying to install this module https://gitlab.e-mips.com.ar/sapel/hotel_reservation_15

and I'm having this issue. I'm doing it with "inv install"

> WARNING devel odoo.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored:
> hotel_reservation_15

Some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have configured your addons_path correctly and also that the spelling of the module in your command (e.g. "odoo-bin -i **hotel_reservation_15**") matches the name of the module's folder.

You can configure the addons_path with the --addons_path command-line option or by passing a configuration file to the odoo-bin script.